# In which conditions can a foreigner be a Shaolin monk?

Tags: kung-fu, shaolin

In which conditions can a foreigner reach the title Shaolin monk?

Should they go to an institute, being in homeland and training at age 4-5?

Is this title reserved for a dedicated group of people?

Comment: As per https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/7719/1780, signs point to that you cannot.

Comment: If you're asking how a foreigner can become a monk at Shaolin Temple, I answered that at the link Macaco Branco mentioned above. You can't. You can become a disciple. It's not the same, but that shouldn't stop you. As for not being a foreigner and instead living in China and raising your kid age 4 or 5, that's a question I've not asked before. I think it's exceedingly rare (almost impossible) for any Chinese born national to be picked to be a monk. For a foreigner's kid, it would be even more impossible. They probably will not take non-Chinese monks, period. I don't know for sure...

Comment: ... Your best bet if you want to train like a monk or want your kid to train like a monk is to become a disciple under a monk and train there for however long you can. Then when you return to your own country, seek out others like you or ex-monks from Shaolin who now live in your country. They get around! You'd be surprised. Take plenty of video. Then train on your own by reminding yourself what to do from watching the video.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could a non-Buddhist person become a monk/master at Shao-lin temple?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/7719/could-a-non-buddhist-person-become-a-monk-master-at-shao-lin-temple)

Comment: Am I the only one that's noticed how many questions about Shaolin we've been getting lately?

Comment: @LemmyX: Things come in waves. Sometimes it's a matter of someone seeing an existing question and thinking, "Hey, I've got something I want to ask about that."

Comment: @shi_yanhao might be able to answer this