# Can a foreigner train shaolin kung fu inside the shaolin temple?

Tags: kung-fu, shaolin

I want to study Shaolin kung fu in China after i finished my school. My first choice is inside the Shaolin temple, but I don't know if that's possible as a foreigner. I would also like to know on what site I can give myself up because I heard that there are a lot of fake sites who say they teach kung fu inside the temple but actually don't. 
Ps. Sorry for my bad english : )

Comment: There is contact info at https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/4535/1780

Comment: My answer here: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/7719/could-a-non-buddhist-person-become-a-monk-master-at-shao-lin-temple/7720#7720

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see "American Shaolin: Flying Kicks, Buddhist Monks, and the Legend of Iron Crotch: An Odyssey in the New China" by Matthew Polly - an interesting read.